# Reading an email address from a Bouncy Castle PGP key

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp

After fighting with the library for some time, I am at a loss for how to get this simple piece of data from a [`PgpPublicKey`](http://boredwookie.net/_documentation/bouncycastle1.7-csharp/html/class_org_1_1_bouncy_castle_1_1_bcpg_1_1_open_pgp_1_1_pgp_public_key.html) object. I've tried the most obvious route, `GetUserAttributes()` but it returns an empty list. `GetUserIds()` returns a list of simple `string` objects, but in the format `"Your Name (comment)"`.

How does one retrieve the email addresses for the key ID's?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Test_ReadPublicKeys(PgpPublicKeyRingBundle publicKeyRingBundle)
{
    foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing publicKeyRing in publicKeyRingBundle.GetKeyRings())
    {
        foreach (PgpPublicKey publicKey in publicKeyRing.GetPublicKeys())
        {
            foreach (object userId in publicKey.GetUserIds())
            {
                //Prints "My_Key_Name (Notes) <my_email@gmail.com>"
                Console.WriteLine(userId); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems, there is no way of pulling just the email from a property or method. String parsing is required.